# Using gulp to watch multiple files within a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp, watch

I was using this gist for my gulpfile: https://gist.github.com/httpNick/708219f5002b6a9dc578

It works great for ES6 babelfiy-ing, but I would like to watch all files within my ./public/js folder and output the built versions to a build folder. Is there a way to modify this gulpfile to watch all js files within the folder?

Copy-pasted from the gist:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')

var browserify = require('browserify')
var watchify = require('watchify')
var babelify = require('babelify')

var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer')
var merge = require('utils-merge')

var rename = require('gulp-rename')
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')


/* nicer browserify errors */
var gutil = require('gulp-util')
var chalk = require('chalk')

function map_error(err) {
  if (err.fileName) {
    // regular error
    gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
      + ': '
      + chalk.yellow(err.fileName.replace(__dirname + '/public/js/', ''))
      + ': '
      + 'Line '
      + chalk.magenta(err.lineNumber)
      + ' & '
      + 'Column '
      + chalk.magenta(err.columnNumber || err.column)
      + ': '
      + chalk.blue(err.description))
  } else {
    // browserify error..
    gutil.log(chalk.red(err.name)
      + ': '
      + chalk.yellow(err.message))
  }

  this.end()
}
/* */

gulp.task('watchify', function () {
  var args = merge(watchify.args, { debug: true })
  var bundler = watchify(browserify('./public/js/index.js', args)).transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
  bundle_js(bundler)

  bundler.on('update', function () {
    bundle_js(bundler)
  })
})

function bundle_js(bundler) {
  return bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', map_error)
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'))
    .pipe(rename('index.min.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
      // capture sourcemaps from transforms
      .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'))
}

// Without watchify
gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  var bundler = browserify('./public/js/index.js', { debug: true }).transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})

  return bundle_js(bundler)
})

// Without sourcemaps
gulp.task('browserify-production', function () {
  var bundler = browserify('./src/js/app.js').transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})

  return bundler.bundle()
    .on('error', map_error)
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(rename('index.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Watchify will watch all the files that get passed to your `browserify` command through the entry point you specify (in your case, `index.js`). So everything required through your `index.js` file should be watched automatically.

It looks like your `watchify` command isn't correct. You're passing your watchify args to the `browserify` function rather than the `watchify` function as you should be.

Here's the relevant portion of my gulpfile, yours is structured a little differently but you'll get the gist in the `watchify` command:

```
.task('js', ['clean'], function() {
    var b = browserify(packageJson.paths.app);

    var w = watchify(b, watchify.args); // Pass watchify.args here vs. in browserify fn.

    w = w 
      .transform(babelify)
      .transform(browserifyShim);

    w.on('update', rebundle);
    function rebundle() {
        // my rebundle function, pretty much same as your `bundle_js`
    }
    return rebundle();
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Yeah that makes sense I will try not passing in my webpack commands to browserify. What exactly is `var b = browserify(packageJson.paths.app);` doing though?

Comment: @httpNick I create my path variables in my `package.json` file and import this into my gulpfile as `packageJson` - this is just a string so it's the exact same as "./public/js/index.js" in your gulpfile.